# In Azure Function App how can I reduce downtime between each yield in orchestration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

In a Node.js Function App on Azure I have an orchestration (generator*) function that calls an series of activity functions. In between each successful activity function there seems to be a period of dead time before the orchestrator is resumed and the next activity is begun. Sometimes it seems very long, like many minutes. Is there anything I can do to make the orchestrator turn over faster? I am on the Premium plan.

Answer (score 1):

Something I have experienced is that, if the output of an activity function is big it creates a dead time before the orchestrator is resumed and the next activity is begun.

Durable Task Saves execution history (also the activity function's output) into table storage. If the output of the activity function becomes big (more than 64kb), it can't save the result in the table column so it saves the result in the blob storage.

Every time the orchestrator function is resumed after waiting for a task to complete, the Durable Task Framework reruns the orchestrator function from scratch and deserializes the blob, and binds to your variable every time. It creates a lot of overhead and slows down the orchestration.